# Attempting to run a Wicket application gets me a 404

Tags: jakarta-ee, wicket

I have the logic of my application all sorted. It's just the "getting the application to run" bit, I'm having issues with.

I know I need (and have) a class that starts the application by showing the home page (in my case, called "UserPage"). However, even after filling out my web.xml correctly, and implementing the WicketApplication class, I still get the 404.

The code for both is below. Could someone please assist me in two ways:

• Telling me where I've gone wrong (and why)

• What the two files need to look like, and where the corrections go.

Thanks in advance.

WicketApplication.java

```
    package com.me.textboxformtutorial;

import com.me.textboxformtutorial.UserPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;

public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
     public Class<UserPage> getHomePage()
    {
        return UserPage.class;
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WicketTextBoxExample</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>UserPage</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WicketTextBoxExample</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/textboxexample</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
        <filter-name>wicketFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>com.me.textboxformtutorial.WicketApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that Wicket pages aren't servlets. Wicket is a framework which adds its own abstraction layer to handling requests and rendering the results and therefore you don't need to declare all your pages separately in the `web.xml`.

The correct way to set Wicket up is to map the filter you defined to the desired url:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>wicketFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> <!-- or /textboxexample/* if you want your application to map to that url -->
</filter-mapping>
```

And delete these entries:

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>WicketTextBoxExample</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>UserPage</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>WicketTextBoxExample</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/textboxexample</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

This feeds all requests for a given url into the Wicket filter, which will handle and parse them, and hand them off to the appropriate page.

If you use Maven, you can create your project from the [Wicket Quickstart Archetype (`archetypeGroupId=org.apache.wicket, archetypeArtifactId=wicket-archetype-quickstart`](https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html), which does it all for you.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much :) World's smallest filter, if I ever saw one. I take it that because my Java file hasn't been mentioned, it's OK? I will let you know if things have worked out.